# Extracting String with Phing

Tags: php, build, phing

I got a directory structure like this:

```
plugins (directory)
- file1.php
- file1.xml
- file2.php
- file2.xml
- file3.php
- file3.xml
...
```

What i need is a directory structure like this:

```
plugins (directory)
- file1 (directory)
-- file1.php
-- file1.xml
- file2 (directory)
-- file2.php
-- file2.xml
- file3 (directory)
-- file3.php
-- file3.xml
...
```

I'm trying to achive that with Phing (has to be phing) like this:

```
<foreach param="file" absparam="absfilename" target="constructplugins">
  <fileset dir="${dir.root}/plugins/">
    <include name="*.php"/>
  </fileset>
</foreach> 

<target name="constructplugins"  description="constructplugins">
<mkdir dir="${dir.tmp}/build/plugins/${file}" />
<copy file="${absfilename}" todir="${dir.tmp}/build/plugins/${file}" />
</target>
```

Like you already see i get a direcory name like "file1.php". I have no idea how to cut the ".php" to create the proper dir, as phing mappers wont work here. And i have also no idea how to copy the xml file. This has to be generic and the build runs under windows xp.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but it should be possible with 'PhpEvalTask'.

```
<foreach param="file" absparam="absfilename" target="constructplugins">
  <fileset dir="${dir.root}/plugins/">
    <include name="*.php"/>
  </fileset>
</foreach> 

<target name="constructplugins"  description="constructplugins">
  <php expression="preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', ${file})" returnProperty="filename"/>
  <mkdir dir="${dir.tmp}/build/plugins/${filename}" />
  <copy file="${absfilename}" todir="${dir.tmp}/build/plugins/${filename}/${file}" />
</target>
```

I might get around to testing it later.